# Removing BIOS password

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bios, passwords, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell inspiron n4110. I set the password for the BIOS but now I forgot that password. I don't want to open the laptop. Can updating the BIOS solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the CMOS battery for several minutes, then plug it back in. This should remove the password. I think that the service manual can come in handy:

> ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-14r-n4110_service%20manual_en-us.pdf

Comment: Thank you Ghassan but I said I don't want to open the laptop! The solution I'm looking for is a software one.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I missed that bit. Courtesy of skimming. You can try the BIOS recovery utilities. You don't have anything to lose by updating. If it does not work, it wont break anything. i also found this:
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ecae94af-87f3-4942-9a8f-8cefe98ba128/recover-bios-password

Comment: No problem, it's fine. And thank you very much for your help. I'm so sorry, I don't have such reputation to give your answer a vote.